# Continuity of a piecewise function.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

I have the following function

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x & \text{if } x \le 1 \\
x^2 & \text{if }x>1
\end{cases}
$$

How do I show that this function is continuous at $x_0=1$?

Comment: I have tried to use the epsilon delta definition but I am not sure which condition to use.

Comment: Show that the two limits, from left and right, for $x \to 1$ exist and have the same value.

Comment: Hint: the continuity at a point $x_0$ satisfies three conditions: (1) $f(x_0)$ is defined; (2) $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) $ exists, and (3) $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) = f(x_0).$

Comment: Could I also use epsilon delta proof. If I can, do I have to show for both cases then?